# Excessive message re-deliveries when consuming from Pubsub

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub

I am noticing a lot of message re-deliveries in my application, even though I have configured max ack deadline for subscription (600 seconds). I am using the async client api for pull-based subscriptions.

Here is an example of the redelivery from my logs:

```
xxx@XXX-MacBook-Pro Downloads % grep 4352639842273916 ~/Downloads/a.txt 
2022/04/08 15:07:01.123 DEBUG [PubsubConsumerImpl] [Gax-11] #### RECEIVE : 4352639842273916
2022/04/08 15:07:01.123 DEBUG [PubsubConsumerImpl] [Gax-11] #### QUEUED : 4352639842273916
#### RETURNED : 33 : 4352639842273916
2022/04/08 15:07:05.332 DEBUG [PubsubMessageQueue] [github_events__0__0__20220408T2206Z] ### ACK 33 : 4352639842273916
2022/04/08 15:07:05.333 DEBUG [PubsubMessageQueue] [github_events__0__0__20220408T2206Z] ### clear ack 33:4352639842273916
#### 33 : 4352639842273916
2022/04/08 15:07:07.043 DEBUG [PubsubConsumerImpl] [Gax-13] #### RECEIVE : 4352639842273916
2022/04/08 15:07:07.043 WARN [PubsubConsumerImpl] [Gax-13] #### DUPLICATE : 4352639842273916
2022/04/08 15:07:57.352 DEBUG [PubsubConsumerImpl] [Gax-29] #### RECEIVE : 4352639842273916
2022/04/08 15:07:57.352 DEBUG [PubsubConsumerImpl] [Gax-29] #### QUEUED : 4352639842273916
#### RETURNED : 81 : 4352639842273916
2022/04/08 15:07:57.406 DEBUG [PubsubMessageQueue] [github_events__0__1__20220408T2207Z] ### ACK 81 : 4352639842273916
2022/04/08 15:07:57.407 DEBUG [PubsubMessageQueue] [github_events__0__1__20220408T2207Z] ### clear ack 81:4352639842273916
#### 81 : 4352639842273916
2022/04/08 15:08:49.184 DEBUG [PubsubConsumerImpl] [Gax-41] #### RECEIVE : 4352639842273916
2022/04/08 15:08:49.184 DEBUG [PubsubConsumerImpl] [Gax-41] #### QUEUED : 4352639842273916
#### RETURNED : 130 : 4352639842273916
2022/04/08 15:08:49.237 DEBUG [PubsubMessageQueue] [github_events__0__2__20220408T2208Z] ### ACK 130 : 4352639842273916
2022/04/08 15:08:49.237 DEBUG [PubsubMessageQueue] [github_events__0__2__20220408T2208Z] ### clear ack 130:4352639842273916
#### 130 : 4352639842273916
```

If you look at the line with “DUPLICATE”, it is getting re-delivered within 6 seconds and also, through a different grpc thread (Gax-11 and Gax-13) . Why is the same message being delivered to 2 different threads?

Fyi, in my application, I am trying to consume a batch of messages and ack them all when the processing is complete. I verified that my code is invoking ACK on all the processed messages. I am using flow control to manage the batch of consumed messages. But it doesn't seem to improve the duplicates situation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of receiving duplicate messages is that the subscriber is too slow to process and acknowledge messages within the deadline even though the maximum ack deadline is set high.. The solution that can be provided at this time is to reduce the subscriber’s queue size means reducing the number of messages that the subscriber pulls at a time.  This way the subscriber will have less messages to process within the deadline.

You can reduce the number of outstanding messages for your subscriber. You can try by setting low values to the subscriber.

The reasons for the duplication behavior in  subscriptions are  due to :

- Messages in the subscriber’s queue are not being processed and ACK'd
  within the deadline.
- The client library continues to (automatically)    extend the
  deadline hoping to be able to process these messages    eventually.
- At some point, after several deadline extensions the    client
  library gives up, so those messages are dropped and    redelivered.
- Messages in Pub/Sub are delivered in batches, so not only the expired messages will be redelivered but also the ones belonging to these messages batches.
- The subscriber will have its    queue full of duplicates, which slows
  down backlog consumption; The    problem becomes worse and worse
  since current duplicates will expire    as well and generate new
  duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although I have eliminated all the possible causes you have listed above - msgs not being ackd within deadline, auto extension of deadline, dropped etc. My logs indicate that the configured ack deadline (10 minutes) is not being honored and message is re-delievered, even though ack was already sent. 
Additionally, the message was being received in 2 different underlying threads, which is unexplainable.

Comment: Fwiw, once we moved from `1.114.*` to `1.116.3` , the amount of duplicates was significantly lower and it looks like the configured ack deadline was being honored by the client library. 
Something seems to have changed in one of the underlying libraries and I couldn't trace out what that change was from the pubsub release notes/changelogs. I do know that 1.116.3 has exactly once in preview. So likely an underlying bug got resolved.